# Make a DataMember in a DataContract use implicit cast to string operator

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

Anyone know if it's possible to use attributes only to make DataContract serialization use the implicit cast to string operator of the type of a property in a class?

For instance:

```
[DataContract]
public class Root
{
    [DataMember]
    public Element Member { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    private string value;

    private Element(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Element element)
    {
        return element.value != null ? element.value : "";
    }

    public static implicit operator Element(string value)
    {
        if (Something()) return new Element(value);
        throw new InvalidCastException()
    }
}
```

(This is just written by hand in a hurry, disregard any compilation issues etc.)

Lars-Erik

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How would you expect the system to deserialize the string back to an Element?

Comment: I would expect it to implicitly convert it back and forth using the two operators defined. It could've been as easy as having a property of the DataMember attribute called type. IE. [DataMember(Type=typeof(string))]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this (easier than dealing with serialization issues) would be something like this :

```
[DataContract]
public class Root
{
    [DataMember]
    public string MemberString { get{ return (string)this.Member; } set{this.Member=(Element)value;} }

    public Element Member { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I guess I have to go that way, yes. The drawback is that I'm trying to deserialize a command that has a domain value type from a dto having an enum. I guess I have to clutter the value type with a string member.

Comment: I figure I'll swap to the enum on the command too and let it convert to the value type when it executes. Meaning Element becomes ElementEnum which is known outside the domain.

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason for not doing this. Data Contracts are supposed to be simple cross-platform data transfer objects so I wouldn't put magic there. Create a non-serializable accessor property converting basic type to what you need.

Comment: See comment on next post.. :)